# Install Neo4j 2.1 on redhat 6.x

Tags: neo4j, centos, installation, redhat

I downloaded and unzipped the package on redhat.

```
ls
bin          conf  lib           LICENSE.txt  plugins     system
CHANGES.txt  data  LICENSES.txt  NOTICE.txt   README.txt  UPGRADE.txt


bin ls -lt
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  4096 Jan 25 00:04 lib
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 10521 Jul 24  2014 neo4j
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  4404 Jul 24  2014 neo4j-installer
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  3443 Jul 24  2014 neo4j-shell
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   478 Jul 24  2014 org.neo4j.server.plist
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   138 Jul 24  2014 README.txt
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 10263 Jul 24  2014 utils


bin ./neo4j-installer install
WARNING: this installer is deprecated and may not be the optimal way to install Neo4j on your system.
Please see the Neo4j Manual for up to date information on installing Neo4j.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the install script you can simply start the Neo4j server by running `path/to/neo4j/bin/neo4j start`.

There is also an experimental YUM package [here](http://yum.neo4j.org/)